# Is it possible install Windows and Linux on a USB device?

Tags: windows, linux, usb-flash-drive, multi-boot

It is easy to install Ubuntu on a USB device.

I can install Windows 7 on USB with [the help of `nt6.zip`](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/win7onusb). But how can I install both Windows and Linux on USB?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be any problem to install windows and GNU/Linux on an external hdd. This should work in exactly the same way as installing to an internal hdd.

Comment: But when you install windows 7, it allocate a new partition of disk.

Comment: I don't understand your sentence and what you mean by that, but to install Windows 7 and GNU/Linux in dual boot, install Windows  7 first (create an extra partition for GNU/Linux in the windows installer) and then install GNU/Linux to the other partition. If you forgot to create the second partition, use Gparted to shrink the windows 7 partition and use the free space to create a new partition to install GNU/Linux to.